# How do I search a folder excluding one specific subfolder?

Tags: finder, spotlight, folders, search

I have this folder structure:

```
Photos
|- Bangalore
|- Sydney
|- Videos
```

How do I search in Photos excluding the Videos subfolder?

I don't want to permanently exclude the subfolder from Spotlight, just for this particular search.

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the directory structure in your example and assuming you wish to search for the files whose extension, for example, includes the keyword `mpv` under the `Photos` directory or any of its subdirectories, but not the `Videos` directory right under it, you can use the `find` command through the Terminal app as follows:

```
find . -name "*.*mpv*" -o -path ./Videos -prune
```

The command above assumes you are in the `Photos` directory in the Terminal app as you issue this command.

If you wish to search for the files whose extensions include either the keyword `mpv` or just `avi` with other criteria being the same as above, you can use the following `find` command:

```
find . \( -name "*.*mpv*" -o -name "*.avi" \) -o -path ./Videos -prune
```

You can search for as many extensions as you like at the same time using `find` by adding more keywords in between `\(` and `\)` as shown above. `-o` serves as the logical operator OR.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for all videos irrespective of extension: m4v, mp4, 3gp, avi, vob, dat... How is that possible using find? Please also give me the Finder solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not update the answer with an option involving the Finder because it does not work as I thought it would and I doubt it is possible to do it with the Finder. However, I included another example of `Find` with the Terminal app that I thought might be useful.